# Custom cursor is pixelating on Windows OS

Tags: javascript, html, css, chromium, text-cursor

I have implemented custom cursor, but it looks pixelated(specially 1366 * 768 resolution) on Windows Chrome (didn't check on Mac OS).
you can see the code snippet here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">
    <style>
        body {
            cursor: -webkit-image-set( url("https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png") 1x, url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png") 2x) 0 0, auto;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Testing
  </body>
</html>
```

Also i changed png to svg image, but got no success.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Please find the stack snippet for the same:**

```css
 body {
            width: 999px;
            height: 500px;
            cursor: -webkit-image-set( url("https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png") 1x, url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png") 2x) 0 0, auto;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">
  </head>
  <body>
    Testing
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't see it with that snippet since those image assets don't exist; if they're small enough, you could embed them using a data URI, or upload them to imgur via the image tool in the question editor, then copy and paste the URL into the code. Wrap it up in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), and then we can see something...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have added stack snippet.

Comment: could it be because of a high dpi screen?

Comment: It is pixelated more in High dpi screen.

Comment: This brings back memories of IE4 and netscape navigator

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{

  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
cursor:-webkit-image-set( url(http://www.ivank.net/veci/crosshair.png) 5x  ) 40 40, auto;
}
```

```html
<body style="">

-webkit-image-set( url(http://www.ivank.net/veci/crosshair.png) 5x  ) 40 40, auto;

</body>
```

I found one more solution, that is working fine, as you required:

http://www.ivank.net/veci/cursors_dpr.html

Have a look.

I am not sure how `Cursor` `image-set` is working, but I doubt it is not working with absolute `URL`, as per my observation, `image-set` `URL` is working with static `URI`. But I tried to change the Static `URI` with Absolute `URL` and it worked well too.

Please have a look, this might help you more.

PS: image URL http://www.ivank.net/veci/crosshair.png

Answer (score -1):

okay this is different approach to use custom cursor

```js
// find elements
$(function () {
  $("#testarea").mousemove(function (e) {
    $(".cursor").show().css({
      "left": e.clientX,
      "top": e.clientY
    });
  }).mouseout(function () {
    $(".cursor").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#testarea {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: none;
}
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: -100px;
  cursor: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="testarea"></div>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png" alt="Cursor" class="cursor" />
```

Answer (score -3):

Okay try this, it's working fine for me.

cursor implementation in css can be done like following format

```
cursor: url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png"), url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png"), default;
```

Not like this:

```
    cursor: -webkit-image-set( url("https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png") 1x, url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png") 2x) 0 0, auto;
```

Have a look to the following code snippet.

```css
    
 body {
            width: 999px;
            height: 500px;
cursor: url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png"), url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png"), default;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CSS Custom Cursor</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying this is a fix? Or are you saying there is nothing wrong with his code?

Comment: I am saying, may be issue with CSS, if I can have his Cursor icon, I can try to make it work. I think in OP code problem is CSS and then the icons :|

Comment: @DupinderSingh added stack snippet for the same. please check.

Comment: Have a look now, Run my code snippet, see its working fine as you required. PS: it takes time to load icon in browser window, so sometime it take seconds to show arrow icon to your custom cursor icon

Comment: This is running in Chromium as well as Mozilla browsers too. 

Comment: @DupinderSingh  I am not getting any difference between the cursors implemented by your code snippet and mine.you can check the difference by running by the code that i have provided.

Comment: This is yours            `cursor: -webkit-image-set( url("https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png") 1x, url("http://i.imgur.com/vf3qXmT.png") 2x) 0 0, auto;` and this is mine `cursor: url("https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png"), url("https://i.imgur.com/gbSYdYW.png"), default;`

Comment: @DupinderSingh I am not talking about the difference in code snippet. i am talking about the sharpness of cursor. both(your and mine) of cursor is pixelating. both cursor looks same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211147/discussion-between-dupinder-singh-and-mukund-kumar).